# Extract data from two tables to summary report based on primary key

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two Excel sheets, one called `plan` and other one called `sewing data`. I want to extract data from `sewing data` sheet to a summary report. Both sheet contain primary key and some data comes from `plan` sheet and others come from `sewing data`.

---

Sample data:

```
[plan]
ID | Style | SO    | QTY
---+-------+-------+------
1  |  a    | 20050 | 100 
2  |  b    | 20051 | 100


[sewing data]
ID | Day1in | Day1out | Day2in | Day2out | Day3in | Day3out
---+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+-----------
1  | 20     |         |  10    |   25    |        |
2  |        |         |  50    |         |        |
2  |        |         |        |         |   50   |  70
1  |        |         |        |         |   70   |  75
```

And my output should be like:

```
[summery report]
ID | Style | SO   | Qty | Day1in | Day1out | Day2in |Day2out|Day3in| Day3out
---+-------+------+-----+--------+---------+--------+-------+------+-----------
1  |  a    |20050 |100  |  20    |         |  10    |   25  |  70  |   75
2  |  b    |20051 |100  |        |         |   50   |       |  50  |   70
```

Comment: We can help you on your tried code and about programming, please add more details like sheets structure and output and your tried code ;).

Comment: there is no any code for this i am extracting data from sumif function in excel and if you need both excel sheet pls tell me how to upload the sheets to this

Comment: You don't need to upload all your data, just give us some sample data and output as I edit on your post, Please edit it to what you want ;).

Comment: ok plan data is as follow

Comment: pls see the above for example and hope you are clear on this

Comment: Have you checked the `VLOOKP` function or `MATCH`? ;).

Comment: no i have used sumif function for this its to slow to load there are 7000 rows and in plan sheet and may have 25000 rows in sewing data sheet. so need to automate this

Comment: `SUMIF` is OK and as you say is slow, so you need a VBA code in a macro ;).

Comment: that would be great if you could develop a VBA

Comment: any positive feedback regarding this

Comment: I've repaired your [tag:execl] tag to the correct [tag:excel] tag. Perhaps this will receive the proper attention it deserves. btw, people looking for VBA code are generally expected to show level of original effort. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a **gimme teh codez** site.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the [plan] sheet, create a named range 'plandata' to cover the plan
   data

   2. On the [sewing data] sheet, add 3 columns, headed Style, SO, Qty, with
      formulas

   =vlookup(A2, plandata, 2, false)
   =vlookup(A2, plandata, 3, false)
   =vlookup(A2, plandata, 4, false)

respectively (here A2 is the reference to the ID cell, plandata is the named range from the [plan] sheet you created in step 1, numbers 2/3/4 are the column numbers you need for the lookup, i.e. Style, SO, and Qty, and false means exact match for the lookup).

3. Copy these formulas down the entire [sewing data] sheet
4. Select any cell in [sewing data], then Insert > Pivot Table (select 'new worksheet')
5. In the Pivot Table wizard, drag ID, Style. SO and Qty as row labels,
   and Day1In..Day3Out as ∑ values.

Comment: yes i have used sumif function and vlookup for this and but the meantime there some some error loading the sheet. mean too much time goes to calculate so i need macro for at least spend only 20min to cal this

Comment: Some error? What error? You must be specific. Please be clear what you are asking. No-one can help you if you are vague like this. Also, please take more care with your comments and questions "so i need macro for at least spend only 20min to cal this" makes no sense. If you take care with your questions you will find that you often find the answer yourself - and if you do not take care why should we?

Comment: i am really sorry regarding the comment which above and my requirement is, i have two excel sheets and one called plan other one is sewing data as above in plan sheet its contain with 6k rows and in sewing data 25k rows. I am using sumif function for gather the data to another sheet called summary report. this is too slow when open the two document for get the output.

Comment: dear edward just if you can help regarding this pls contact me even my ques is not clear i am here to explain this via skype or any thing b'coz this is really urgent and have to do this in this week

Comment: So to be clear - there is no error, it is just slow, it takes 20 minutes to calculate, it that it?

Comment: yes that is too slow but its take more than 45 mins to calculate the report

Comment: Is your SUMIF on the [Summary Report] sheet? If so, did you try the Pivot Table that I suggested? A Pivot Table should be much faster than SUMIF().

Comment: yes i have used power pivot also due to same value repeating from sewing data report i cant execute it. its always appear ID is nt matching

Comment: Ed if you have time can talk a bit to how to complete this summery report as the requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a one-size-fits-all formula by wrapping the first [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) in an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) which passes control over to a second [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) if the VLOOKUP cannot find the column header label in the first. In B15 as,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A15, $A$3:$D$4, MATCH(B$14, $A$2:$D$2, 0), FALSE), SUMPRODUCT($B$8:$G$11, ($A$8:$A$11=$A15)*($B$7:$G$7=B$14)))
```

Fill right and down as necessary.

[image: iferror_vlookup_vlookup]

It is critically important that the column header labels match exactly; no leading spaces on one or the other.